# Scroll is not showing for an element with percentage width

Tags: css

I have a 2 column layout with fixed left column and a right column that fills the remainder, the inner element's scroll is not showing. I got this layout working with another non-angular project, I'm not sure what is going on with the angular project. How can I get the scroll to show on the `app-table-container`. **Not the right column**, only the child element.

**Angular**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/2-column-fixed-flex-angular

**Non-angular**: (working version): https://stackblitz.com/edit/2-column-fixed-flex

I've set the inner element's scroll overflow:

```
app-table-container {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

**Columns:**

```
.columns {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
}

.left-column {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.right-column {
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    min-height: 0;
    background: lightcoral;
}
```

**Template:**

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="left-column"></div>
  <div class="right-column">
    <app-table-container></app-table-container>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner element is being considered a custom element by the browser and no style is being applied.

Add `display: block` to it as well, the UA stylesheet that makes elements like `<div>` and `<section>` block, and it should work fine. Then, set height and width.

```
app-table-container {
    overflow: scroll;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Also, add `width: 100%` to `.columns`.
Then, more 20px to .right-column, because of vertical scroll width:

```
.right-column {
    width: calc(100% - 120px);
}
```

Comment: no it doesn't, it does effect the element though. Scroll is outside viewport

Comment: you can see on stackblitz link

Comment: Ok. I edited the answer. Please, check if I got it right this time.

Answer (score 0):

```
In the tablecontainer add the CSS and add the div class to table container component HTML.
table-container.componenet.html
    <div class="ex1"><table>
     <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>

    table-container.componenet.scss
    td {
      padding: 20px;
    }



    div.ex1 {
        background-color: lightblue;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```